# GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser nil when relaunching app

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

Initially I was having a problem with the check to see if we have saved data into the keychain. I found this post and followed the suggestion by BhavinBhadani:

> Whenever you check if ([GIDSignIn sharedInstance].hasAuthInKeychain) ,
>   before that add your sign in scopes..

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/27

This has solved my first problem of `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()` returning true after the user has logged in successfully before and then has killed app and re runs.

However now I am doing the following:

```
let signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
signIn.scopes = [Constants.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SCOPE, Constants.GOOGLE_OIDC_SCOPE]

if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
    print("We have saved in keychain")

    if let u = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser {
        getData(dataApi)
    }
    else {
        // THIS CODE IS BEING SUCCESSFULLY HIT
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
        getApplicationData(dataApi)
    }
}
```

However even after doing: `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()` the `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser` is nil.

Has anyone successfully used `signInSilently()` to populate the currentUser data again?

Comment: Please check my answer for google SDK version prior to v5.0.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I make a point in that issue in git that you also need to add scopes before check `hasAuthInKeychain` like this .. this works for me and hope same for you

```
 let signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
signIn.scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"]

  if (signin.hasAuthInKeychain) {
        print("Signed in");
  } else {
        print("Not signed in");
  }
```

> make sure after `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()`, there is some delay to call `getApplicationData(dataApi)` to populate data.

Comment: this is not swift

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the code from the post. The issue as stated in the question is about the currentUser being nil. I also wrote: 'This has solved my first problem of GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() returning true after the user has logged in successfully before and then has killed app and re runs.'. I also asked: 'Has anyone successfully used signInSilently() to populate the currentUser data again?'

Comment: @pls does it gives any log when crashed?

Comment: @ElCaptain - If I put a break point after GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently() it is nil.

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 - I am not really sure what logs you are referring to. When I try to use it I can either force unwrap which gives fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value or if let which doesn't crash. Could you give some more details on what log you would want from an optional in swift?

Comment: @pls just remove this line `getApplicationData(dataApi)` and check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124791/discussion-between-pls-and-ei-captain-v2-0).

Comment: Thanks I was missing stating the scopes from the beginning, `hasAuthInKeychain` always returned `false`

Answer (score 7):

Recently Google has changed the methods for checking if the user has been already loggedIn in Google SignIn SDK v5.0.0.

> Update calls to signInSilently and hasAuthInKeychain to
>   restorePreviousSignIn and hasPreviousSignIn.

So the code will look like

```
if(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasPreviousSignIn()) {

      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()

  } else {

    navigateToLogin()

 }
```

Migration guide: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the the after deleting the app. It may possible at the time of login you have not added the Keychain sharing capability to the app. and now when you try to get

```
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()
```

it returns true but current user is still nil.

I had faced the same issue, so deleted the app and did the login again. Now I can see the current user.

Comment: I tried reinstalling the app, but this didn't work for me. It's always `nil`. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

For me, the trick was **enabling 'Keychain Sharing' in Capabilities**.

**So my receipt is:**

- Set scopes
- 'hasAuthInKeychain' check
- True means we can 'signInSilently', otherwise normal signIn
- **If we check 'currentUser' just afterward it will be nil**, the right place to get it is in GIDSignInDelegate method - didSignInFor user:

  ```
  func authCheck() {

  let signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()

  signIn?.scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]

  if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
      // The user has either currently signed in or has previous authentication saved in keychain.
      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
  } else {
      showLoginScene()
  }}

  func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
        withError error: Error!) {

  if let error = error {
      print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
  } else {
      // Now currentUser has value
  guard let currentUser = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser else {
          print("currentUser is nil")
          return nil
  }
  }}
  ```