# GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser returns nil (when a user was previously signed in) for first few seconds when app launches

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have an app whose layout is based on `UINavigationControllers`. This app has a RootVC that has a table view, and clicking its cells takes the users to different view controllers.

RootVC
|--- MainVC 
|--- DiscussionsVC (Is `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()`'s delegate and presentingViewController)
|--- InfoVC

In all of the child view controllers `viewDidLoad` method, I have added the following print statement:

```
print("Google User (View Controller Name): ", GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser)
```

Initially, `MainVC` is pushed on `viewVillAppear` of `RootVC`, making it the first screen visible to the user.
The value of `currentUser`is nil in `RootVC` and `MainVC`. However, if I go back to the `RootVC` and navigate to `InfoVC` or `DiscussionsVC`, then `currentUser` is not `nil`. So I tried making the first presented VC to `InfoVC` and now `currentUser` is `nil` there. So I changed the code for printing in `MainVC` and `currentUser` is not `nil` anymore.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30) {
   print("Google User (Main VC): ", GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser)
}
```

I think it takes some time for the value of `currentUser` to not be `nil`. So I have 2 questions:

1. What is the appropriate amount of time to wait before checking for `currentUser`
2. Is there something that I can add to make the setting of `currentUser` instantaneous? [Some post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830457/gidsignin-sharedinstance-currentuser-nil-when-relaunching-app) suggested adding this, which did not help.

```
if(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasPreviousSignIn()) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()
}
```

#### Edit 1

I tried adding the following lister as mentioned in the answer, but `user` is still `nil` after a long time.

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
    print("Auth state changed: \n AUTH: \n\(auth)\nUSER \n\(user)")
    if let user = user {
        print("User is not nil")
    }
}
```

This is how I am signing the user in initially, am I missing something with the firebase auth?

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
            // ...
            if let error = error {
                // ...
                print("Error signing in")
                print(error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                           accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
            
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("authentication error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
            setUserProfileImage()
        }
```

#### Edit 2

I think it's working now after I enabled Google signin via firebase console. Though it said in the console that Google sigin is enabled by default for iOS and Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Firebase Authentication is based on a combination of a long lived refresh token, and short lived ID tokens. When the app is started, Firebase connects to the server to get a new ID token. While this call is going on, the `currentUser` is `nil`.

To better respond to the user authentication state, use an authentication state listener as shown in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
  // ...
}
```

This callback will automatically be called by Firebase once it has (succeeded or failed to) refresh the ID token.

Comment: this is for firebase auth. What about the subpart of it which is gmail auth?

Comment: Yup! Waited for more than a minute, the user is still nil.